# How do you apply ChildOf evenly to an entire object?

Tags: animation, modifiers, constraints

I know that the title is a bad one! I am not sure what to call this. I have two models - the character and a quiver/bow. The quiver/bow object is using the Child Of constraint to follow the second spine bone.

As you can see from the below gif, when I switch animations the quiver adjusts, but the bow doesn't. The Bow and Quiver were separate objects that I joined together and then reapplied the constraint. It seems that the Influence is being applied differently to each object.

In this first gif, the influence is set to zero and the quiver behaves as I'd expect, but the bow does not.

[image]

[image]

In the second gif, the influence is set to 1 and the bow behaves properly, but the quiver does not:

[image]

Any idea on how I can fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can suppose from your gifs, the Bow is  reacting  correctly while the quiver is getting a so-called double trasform: Child of constraint (which is in action only when its influence slider is not 0.0) is moving the origin of the Bow-quiver object, while probably an armature modifier is moving every vertex of the quiver only.

To solve select  the bow-quiver object and delete its armature modifier and/or all its animation related vertex groups.